# Additional "where column is not null" significantly slows down a query execution time

Tags: sql-server, execution-time

In SQL Server I have a query:

```
select 
    a, b, year(c), max(convert(date,c)), d
from 
    some_view
where
    a is not null
    and b = 'str1'
    and (x in ('str2','str3', ...) or a = 'str4')
    --and c is not null
    --and d is not null
group by
    a, b, year(c), d
```

The execution time is 6 seconds.

If I uncomment `--and c is not null` the execution time is 6 or 5 seconds.

If I uncomment `--and d is not null` I don't know the execution time because I haven't waited for the query to finish.

Why uncommenting `--and d is not null` makes the execution time soar?

Comment: whats the table structure, datatypes, indices an so on?

Comment: take a look at the query plan.

Comment: How many rows with d as null in the table? What is the datatype of column d?

Comment: Making varchar column to index is bad idea .Real problem lies in your  table design or in real query that exists in view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the execution plan? My money would be on an index issue. If your query is using an index that has d as an included column rather than indexed column then it's likely to force a scan of the table/index which will kill your performance. Run the execution plan with and without those IS NULL statements, that's going to point you towards what the issue is. Check for index hints when you do this.